# Unable to replace the default search icon using CSS in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: search, css

I tried to replace the default search icon in the search box by using the following code

`.ms-InlineSearch-DivBaseline .ms-InlineSearch-Outline-Baseline .ms-inlineSearch-searchImgSpanBase > img{ 
    background-image:url('Icons/custom-icon.png') !important ;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block;
}`

Image tag has an inline styling with src="location of default image",and it is not allowing to override the CSS even with !important specified.
How can we change the default icon with our custom icon.
Note: Targeting the img tag is correct as I applied display:none,it did hid the default image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link should help you [here](http://erikswenson.blogspot.in/2010/01/change-sharepoint-search-icon-with-just.html,
below is extract from same post what you need to follow is:

Upload your custom images to a sub folder within the following directory: `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\12\TEMPLATE\IMAGES\YourCustomFolder`

Then in your custom CSS simply place the following CSS:

```
td.ms-sbgo{ 
    background-color:transparent; 
    padding-left:3px; 
    padding-right:3px; 
    padding-bottom:0px; 
    padding-top:0px; 
    border:solid 0px #949494; 
} 

td.ms-sbgo a{ 
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important; 
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px !important; 
}

td.ms-sbgo a{ 
    background-image: url(/_layouts/images/yourcustomfolder/custom_search.gif); 
    background-repeat: no-repeat; 
    background-position: top left; 
} 

td.ms-sbgo a img{ 
    visibility: hidden; 
    height: 17px; 
    width: 17px; 
}
```

Comment: This is for 2010, while the question specifically mentions 2013

Answer (score 0):

Following options cans be used:

1. CSS

   ```
   td.ms-sbgo
   {
       padding:0px 3px 0px 3px;
   }

   td.ms-sbgo a
   {
       background-image: url(/Style%20Library/Images/our_search_button.png);
       background-repeat: no-repeat;
       background-position: top left;
       display:block;
       width:20px;
       height:19px;
   }

   td.ms-sbgo a img
   {
       display: none;
   }
   ```
2. Use some jQuery to modify the HTML for the searchbox.

   You can target the `srch-gosearchimg` CSS class to modify the image tag and point it to another source image.
3. Use a delegate control to replace the entire searchbox

   - You will need server access for this.
     [Delegate control to customize small search box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms463169.aspx)

Comment: you sure that td.ms is SP 2013 SP class or 2010's?